# Nested template classes with pointer-to-method not compiled in clang++

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang++

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of my problem is:

```
template <class T> class MyClass
{
  template <void (MyClass::*M)() const> struct wrapper
  {
    virtual void call();
  };
};

template <typename T>
template <void (MyClass<T>::*M)() const>
void MyClass<T>::wrapper<M>::call()
{
}
```

This code compiled in gcc but failed with error:

```
error: nested name specifier 'MyClass<T>::wrapper<M>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
void MyClass<T>::wrapper<M>::call()
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

in clang++. **Why?**

In class *call* definition solves the problem, I know. Any non pointer-to-method templates works fine everywhere. Experiments with *template/typename* has no result.

Comment: It looks like nobody on SO knows the answer, so maybe you could submit a Clang bug and then post here if you get a response.

Comment: @Brian, OK. https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24357 Waiting...

Comment: Your SSCCE lacks command line switches and version numbers.

Comment: Also your error doesn't match your SSCCE (MyClass3). Its minor but I've found its the kind of thing that will have people overlook a valid/interesting question.

Comment: @kfsone, output fixed, thanks. Compiler switches are as simple as (g++|clang++) <filename>. It's obvious

Comment: What is the output of `clang++ --version`?

Comment: `Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix`

Comment: @dyomas Please include this information in your question. It might get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround: consider using std::function instead of wrapper. It is not exactly the same (less constraint on which function pointers are acceptable) but it will compile on clang++ and simplify your code.

```
#include <functional>

template <class T> class MyClass
{
    typedef std::function<void(void) const > wrapper;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can move the implementation of method  in the class definition :

```
template <class T> class MyClass
{
    template <void (MyClass::*M)() const> struct wrapper
    {
        virtual void call(){/* move implementation here */};
    };
};
```

Comment: See above: _In class call definition solves the problem, I know_